# Change default app to open TXT files on MacOs Mojave

Tags: macos, macos-mojave

I'm trying to change the default app that handles txt files from native TextEdit to Brackets. To achieve this, i'm doing :

1 - Click on a TXT file with the right mouse button, Open With > Other

2 - Select Brackets on the list and check Always open with

3 - Click Open.

After that, i get the error screen below. How can i achieve this task ?

[image]

Comment: Open your chosen app first, by right click/Open. That should inform Gatekeeper. Then you can right click the txt file & open with.

Comment: @Tetsujin I can use Open with, but when i try to change the default app in the Open With window, i get the error above.

Comment: Did you make sure the app would open first? if you don't tell Gatekeeper you want it to launch, it will refuse if you try to do your 'open with' before authorising the app.

Answer (score 0):

I think the steps you were trying would normally work, but it looks like your text file was likely quarantined (browsers and mail clients usually quarantine "unsafe" files by default, and text files are considered unsafe because they could be shell scripts).

The quarantine marker is stored as an "extended attribute", which is a kind of metadata attached to the file in the filesystem's data structures. The exact ID of the quarantine attribute is "com.apple.quarantine". The `xattr(1)` command can be used to create, view, edit, and delete extended attributes.

So, first remove the quarantine (extended attribute) from the text file you're trying to open:

```
xattr -d com.apple.quarantine codes.txt
```

…then follow the steps you were already trying.